# Testing a Python API client

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

This question is based on 
[How do I test an API Client with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717595/how-do-i-test-an-api-client-with-python)

```
class MyClient(...):

    def _do_get(self, suffix):
         return requests.get(self.service_url + "/" + suffix).json()

    def do_stuff(self):
         return self._do_get("stuff")
```

This is an example client and the answer provider said to mock the method that makes the requests:

```
class MyClientWithMocks(MyClient):

     def _do_get(self, suffix):
          self.request_log.append(suffix)
          return self.send_result
```

and use it like this:

```
def test_stuff(self):
    client = MyClientWithMocks(send_result="bar")
    assert_equal(client.do_stuff(), "bar")
    assert_contains(client.request_log, "stuff")
```

Wouldn't you mock the function that is getting request (which is `requests.get`)  rather than mocking `_do_get`? Also, is it better to have the function that creates the path `do_stuff` to call `_do_get` and have `_do_get` return necessary output for easier testing?